# Difference between splitting a string with character and string in scala

Tags: string, scala, split, character

I am splitting a string based on a pipe `|` character in scala. I see two different options to do this. I am surprised to see I got two different results in different scenarios.

Check this out:

> [image]

In case of string, it also returned pipe character while in case of character it returned the results as expected.

I am curious to know the difference in both of these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is when you are providing a `String` parameter this `String` can be a regular expression. And `|` is a special character in the world of regular expressions.

This will become more clear to you after following example,

```
scala> val s1 = "abcdef"
s1: String = abcdef

scala> s1.split("|")
res7: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

If you want to get the desired result you will have to escape `|` using `\\`

```
scala> val s1 = "abcdef"
s1: String = abcdef

scala> s1.split("\\|")
res7: Array[String] = Array(abcdef)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of string it needs escaping. use `"\\|"` instead of `"|"`

```
scala> "a|b|c|d".split("|")
res19: Array[String] = Array(a, |, b, |, c, |, d)

scala> "a|b|c|d".split("\\|")
res20: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d)

scala> "a|b|c|d".split('|')
res21: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d)

scala> "a|b|c|d".split("""\|""")
res23: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d)
```

Answer (score 1):

A few more ways of escaping a regex:

```
scala> "a|b|c|d".split(raw"\|")
res114: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d)

scala> "a|b|c|d".split(raw"\Q|")
res115: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d)

scala> "a|b|c|d".split("""\Q|""")
res116: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d)

scala> "a|b|c|d".split("\\Q|")
res117: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d)
```

Note that variables are interpolated in `raw` strings, so one needs to be careful with `$`.

`\Q` is particularly useful when you have several characters to escape and don't want to put a backslash before each of them.